# Heatmap with multiple/stacked variables per individual

Tags: r, ggplot2, pheatmap

I am trying to create a heatmap. Each individual has three binary variables (ecz, whz, rhi) across 6 time points. The attached heatmap isn't at all informative as I want to see how the variables develop concurrently.

For each individual rows), I would like 3 rows per individual at each time point with 3 different colours to represent each symptom. The columns would represent each of the 6 time points. [image: Heatmap]

I would be most grateful for any help!

Here is my data:

```
structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 
39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L), .Dim = c(50L, 19L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("idno", 
"eczms1", "whzms1", "rhims1", "eczms3", "whzms3", "rhims3", "eczms5", 
"whzms5", "rhims5", "eczms8", "whzms8", "rhims8", "eczms11", 
"whzms11", "rhims11", "eczms16", "whzms16", "rhims16")))
```

Here is the code for the attached heatmap:

```
library(pheatmap)
am=as.matrix(am)
col = c("darkgreen","red")
breaks <- c(-1, 0, 1)
c1=pheatmap(am, show_rownames=FALSE, col=col, cluster_rows = FALSE, 
       cluster_cols=FALSE,  legend =TRUE, 
       legend_breaks = 0:1, legend_labels = c("No","Yes"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a solution using the tidyverse packages:

EDIT:
Reordered `idno` so that patients are sorted by appearance of ecz.

```r
library(tidyverse)

input <- structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
                     13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
                     26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 
                     39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 0L, 
                     1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
                     1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
                     0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
                     1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
                     1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                     1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                     0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                     0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                     0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                     0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
                     0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                     1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                     1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
                     0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
                     1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                     1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                     0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                     0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                     0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
                     1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
                     0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
                     0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                     0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                     1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
                     0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
                     0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
                     1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
                     1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
                     0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
                     0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                     0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                     1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
                     1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
                     1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
                     1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                     0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
                     1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
                     1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                     1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                     0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
                     0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                     1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
                     0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
                     0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
                     1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
                     1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                     1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
                     0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
                     1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
                     0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
                     1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
                     0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                     0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                     0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
                     1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                     0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                     1L, 0L, 1L), .Dim = c(50L, 19L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("idno", 
                                                                               "eczms1", "whzms1", "rhims1", "eczms3", "whzms3", "rhims3", "eczms5", 
                                                                               "whzms5", "rhims5", "eczms8", "whzms8", "rhims8", "eczms11", 
                                                                               "whzms11", "rhims11", "eczms16", "whzms16", "rhims16")))

tidy <- tibble::as.tibble(input) %>%
  tidyr::gather(key = "key", value = "value", -idno) %>%
  tidyr::separate(key, into = c("symptom", "time"), sep = "(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])") %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    time = as.factor(as.numeric(time)),
    value = ifelse(value, symptom, NA),
    symptom = factor(symptom, levels = c("eczms", "whzms", "rhims"), labels = c("ecz", "whz", "rhi")),
    idno = factor(idno, levels = unique(idno[order(value)]))
  )

ggplot(tidy, aes(x = time, y = symptom, fill = value)) +
  geom_raster() +
  facet_wrap(~idno) +
  scale_fill_brewer(guide = FALSE, palette = "Set2")
#> Warning: Removed 474 rows containing missing values (geom_raster).
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(tidy, aes(x = time, y = reorder(idno, dplyr::desc(idno)), fill = value)) +
  geom_raster() +
  facet_wrap(~symptom) +
  scale_fill_brewer(guide = FALSE, palette = "Set2")
#> Warning: Removed 474 rows containing missing values (geom_raster).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-11-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: This is fantastic!! Thank you so much. I will try it on my full sample. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: this works great with my data. Please could ask how do I change the order of symptoms so that the charts display the order eczms, whzms, whims? I can see in the data "tidy" they are in that order but the chart displays ecz, rhi, whz. Thank you again!

Comment: Glad to hear it works! The order is determined by the factor levels of the symptoms. By the default their ordering is alphanumeric. To change this, you can add `%>% dplyr::mutate(symptom = factor(symptom, levels = c("eczms", "whzms", "rhims")))` to the function chain where `tidy` is created. To also change their labels, use `%>% dplyr::mutate(symptom = factor(symptom, levels = c("eczms", "whzms", "rhims"), labels = c("ecz", "whz", "rhi")))`

Comment: Perfect  - thank you! One last query. I sorted my data so that those who have eczms at age 1 or 3 appear first in the charts. However, the charts are displayed in order of idno. Do you know how can I sort so that ids who have eczms at time 1 or 3 are displayed first? Thank you again!

Comment: You are the best!! Thank you so much for your help. This is perfect.